# Error while deploying flask app in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

My folder and file details [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jxdi.png)

Error while deploying flask app in heroku [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSqC8.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named `Procfile` without a file extension. For example, `Procfile.txt` is not valid.

This is the reason why Heroku isn't able to find any `web` processes to run. (Error Code H14: No web dynos running)

Fix:

> Change `Procfile.txt` to `Procfile` in root of your repo.

Refer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: still i have the same issue

Comment: web: gunicone main:app      is my procfile .

Comment: Do i need to change that

Comment: This is the format `web: gunicorn main:app` in your `Procfile` where main refers to main.py and app refers to app = Flask(__name__)